# QString::fromStdString crash (c++)

Tags: c++, string, qt, std

I'm trying to convert a std::string to QString using QString::fromStdString

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#include <qtcore/qstring>

int main() {
    string s = "111";
    QString ss = QString::fromStdString(s);
    return 0;
}
```

The simple code throws an exception and crashes, when debugging with vs2010, the call stack are full of msvcr100d.dll, kernel32.dll, ntdll.dll,  nothing helps.
I'm using win7_32bit + QT 5.1.1 + vs2010

Any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: On an unrelated note: When returning from `main` it's customary to return `0` if everything is okay, and a positive value if there was an error.

Comment: Besides the header files (you should really show the complete program, including header file inclusion), does that exact program in the question cause this crash to happen?

Comment: [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstring.html#fromStdString): `This constructor is only available if Qt is configured with STL compatibility enabled.`

Comment: The source code is updated to the complete program, nothing else is included. I can confirm that the line with fromStdString causes the crash, cause the crash happens when I try to step over this line in debugging mode.

Comment: Make sure you don't use release Qt libraries(without `d` suffix) in debug project. Also make sure they are of the same bitness and built by the same compiler.

Comment: @lvaylo Strandjev, 
How to configure QT with STL, I download the "QT for vs2010" from official site, seems it's not configured with STL?

now I got a work around : "QString s = std_string.data()",  but I still want to know how to configure QT with STL

Answer (score 0):

@ixSci, That's it, I'm using the release qt libraries, it works after adding a 'd' to the libraries.

Comment: How did you configure the project to use RELEASE version of the Qt library for RELEASE builds (and vice versa).